# Create series of tibbles running through title by item in list of strings

Tags: dataframe, list, printf, tibble

I have a list of strings:

```
lst = c('item1', 'item2', 'item3', ..., 'itemN')
```

and I have a dataframe `df` with column `df$item` equal to one of `item` in `lst` above. Using a for loop, I would like to create a list of dataframes of the form

`item1_df, item2_df, item3_df, ..., itemN_df`

with each item in the name of the objects as a sub-dataframe of `df` such that `itemi_df$item == itemi` for i in {1,2,3,...,N}.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. But I think that if you want to assing objects in a `for` loop you should use the `assing()` function instead of operator `<-`.

```
lst <- c('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
for(i in lst) {
  assign(paste0(i, "_df"), df[df$item == i,])
}
```